# ActiveAdmin checking create authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, cancancan

To me it seems that [ActiveAdmin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin) should check the create authorization mainly in 2 cases:

- The UI needs to show the "create new Ticket" button: here, it is useful to check wether the current_user has permission to create a generic Ticket.

  [Cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) syntax looks like the following:

  ```
  user.can?(:create, Ticket)
  ```
- ActiveAdmin needs to understand if the resource can actually be stored in the db after a form submission: here it is useful to check wether the current user can store that ticket with the values just "typed in" using the ticket form.

  Cancancan syntax looks like the following:

  ```
   user.can?(:create, Ticket.new({author_id: user.id, some: "x", other: "y", values: "z"}))
  ```

That's it! So why would ActiveAdmin check the following right before showing the generated "create form" for the user?

```
user.can?(:create, Ticket.new({author_id: nil, some: nil, other: nil, values: nil}))
```

What if the current user has only permission to create tickets where `author_id = own_user_id`?

The authorization would fail even before seeing the form.

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain why ActiveAdmin was written that way, but I can show you how I've solved a similar problem.

First, you will need to grant your user the [ability](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/defining-abilities) to create the desired record under all conditions:

```
# app/models/ability.rb
...
  can :create, Ticket
...
```

This will get your past ActiveAdmin's `can?` check and allow the user to see the form.  But we need to make sure the `author_id` belongs to the current user. To do this, you can use the `before_create` callback to set the proper `author_id` before saving:

```
# app/admin/ticket.rb
ActiveAdmin.register Ticket do
...
  before_create do |ticket|
    ticket.author_id = own_user_id
  end
...
end
```

The above assumes you have a helper method or a variable called `own_user_id` that is available to the ActiveAdmin module and returns the proper user id.  If you were using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), you might substitute `current_user.id` for `own_user_id`.

I'll admit, this is a not the cleanest solution, but it works. I have implemented something similar in my own projects.

Comment: that is the ability definition. What i meant using the "can" method was a helper to check if a user can/can't do something.

Comment: that would work but i'd prefer keeping my authorization rules well separated from the rest of the application. Of course this would work for this Ticket example. but i have authorization conditions for all my models.

Comment: I agree.  You can always create a separate (perhaps inherited) ability class for ActiveAdmin.  Not an ideal solution to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

I did override the Data Access class as follows, in order to have it working.

I am:

- disabling authorization that i feel is done in the wrong time
- forced validation before the authorization before saving a resource

  ```
  ActiveAdmin::ResourceController::DataAccess.module_eval do
    def build_resource
      get_resource_ivar || begin
        resource = build_new_resource
          resource = apply_decorations(resource)
        run_build_callbacks resource

        # this authorization check is the one we don't need anymore
        # authorize_resource! resource

        set_resource_ivar resource
      end
    end
  end

  ActiveAdmin::ResourceController::DataAccess.module_eval do
    def save_resource(object)
      run_save_callbacks object do
        return false unless object.validate # added it
        authorize_resource! resource        # added it
        object.save(validate: false)        # disabled validation since i do it 2 lines up
      end
    end
  end
  ```